# C++ typeof operator

Tags: c++, typeof

very short question.

Is C++ `typeof` operator standard?  de facto standard?
which compilers do not provided it (besides Microsoft C++)?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The `typeof` operator is nonstandard, but the upcoming C++ standard will have `decltype`.

Answer (score 12):

As noted, C++0x has `decltype`. You can take a look at [Boost.Typeof](http://beta.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/doc/html/typeof.html) in the meantime.

Answer (score 1):

There is no typeof operator in standard C++.

Answer (score 0):

The typeof is an extension provided by GNU compiler primarily for C language: 
[link to official gnu gcc page](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Typeof.html). So it isn`t a standard operator.